# Ember Nested Routes Break Named Outlet

Tags: ember.js

I have a Parent route named `engineering`.
Every route extends a `Base.js` route which renders the default template as well as another custom one into the named outlet:

```
renderTemplate: function (controller) {
    this.render();

    this.render('page-title', {
        outlet: 'pageTitle',
        controller: controller,
    });
},
```

There is a `engineering.hbs` parent template which contained two outlets. The Main `{{outlet}}` and another `{outlet 'pageTitle'}}`.

This works perfecly fine for routes like `/engineering/index` and `engineering/someothersite`, but the `pageTitle` outlett just doesn't render at all for routes like `engineering/college/courses/description`.

Any Suggestions, or perhaps even a better way of passing data from a child route to the parent template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. For future visitors, the issue was not including the `into` property in the `render` method.

```
this.render('page-title', {
    outlet: 'pageTitle',
    into: controller.topParent,
    controller: controller,
});
```

`controller.topParent` is my own property.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage to use [ember-elsewhere](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere) addon for this purpose instead of using the named outlet.